# Index of character from end of string

Tags: python

I know that to get the index of a character from the end of a string, you do:

```
    str.index(sub, -1)
```

So why does this code produce and error when I call it?

```
    def test(string):
        for letter in string:
            print string.index(letter, -1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rindex#str.index) throws an exception if the substring isn't found, y'know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that to get the index of a character from the end of a string, ...

I think you may be confused here, it does *not* get the index from the end of the string, it gets the index from the *start* of the string, but only starts *searching* from the given index.

This becomes evident if you enter and run the following code:

```
def test(string):
    for letter in 'e':
        print string.index(letter, -1)

test("abcde")
```

and you correctly get `4` as the output, the position of `e` from the string start.

In your code (and the example above), we are telling it to search the *substring* starting at index `-1`, which is just the last character in the string.

So, if your string is `"abc"`, it will first look for `a` in the substring `"c"` and, not finding it, will raise an exception.

Changing your code to:

```
def test(string):
    for letter in string:
        print string.index(letter)
test("abcde")
```

will give you the correct indexes *without* raising an exception.

If you *do* need the index from the end of the string (so that `e` is `0` and `a` is `4`), some simple mathematical manipulation will do it:

```
def test(string):
    for letter in string:
        print len(string) - string.index(letter, 0) - 1
test("abcde")
```

This code gives you, for the letters `a` through `e`:

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

read here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_index.htm or https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find

It did not find it in the location u specified to look for it.
Regardless, try-catch it and see the error.